# Prove that a product of functions of bounded variation is a function of bounded variation

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

We consider functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$. I have to prove that a product of functions of bounded variation is a function of bounded variation. I have to also show that this isn't true for quotient in general and tell which additional assumption guarantees that quotient IS of bounded variation.

Comment: So what did you do so far and what is your question?

Comment: Yes flawr is right. I have given you the key step. If you tried it. You should do it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

$|(fg)(x)-(fg)(y)|\leq |f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)|$. Again $f,g$ are bounded so what will you get from here??

Comment: that $fg$ is bounded?

Comment: If f, g is bounded then it is. You have given f,g has bounded variation right?/

Comment: ohh so each "jump" of $fg$ is bounded

Comment: so now i can take sum over any partition of $[a,b]$

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

This came to my mind first.

$$fg = \frac{(f+g)^2 - (f-g)^2}{4}$$

Since sum of functions of bounded variation have bounded variation, it suffices to show that $f^2$ is of bounded variation when $f$ is. To show the latter, use

$$|f(x)^2-f(y)^2| = |f(x)-f(y)||f(x)+f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|(|f(x)|+|f(y)|)$$

and the fact that $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: $f$ is of bounded variation iff $f=f_1-f_2$ for $f_1,f_2$ positive and increasing. Then $fg=(f_1-f_2)(g_1-g_2)=(f_1g_1+f_2g_2)-(f_1g_2+f_2g_1)$ and we are done.

Comment: But how do you prove the product of 2 increasing functions is increasing? (It's false in fact)

Comment: @Mariana It's true if you suppose them positive.